# RevCommit JGit mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, jgit

My question is about mocking a `RevCommit` object from the JGit library. 
When simply mocking an object of this type and defining it's behaviour, I get an error. For example:

```java
RevCommit revCommitMock = mock(RevCommit.class);        
Mockito.when(revCommitMock.getShortMessage()).thenReturn("ExampleMessage");
```

This will result in a `NullPointerException`.

Probably, the way to do it correctly is calling method:

```
parse(RevWalk rw, byte[] raw)
```

on an instance of `RevCommit` object, but how to do it properly? I get `NullPointerException` parsing mocked object of type `RevWalk`. 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why not just have a local repo included as part of your test data? You won't have to mock anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid the `NullPointerException`, you would need to fully simulate the behaviour of a real `RevCommit`. To get its behaviour right in all aspects, you would end up re-building large parts of the actual `RevCommit` implementation in JGit.

This is why I recommend to run tests against a real repository. For said reasons, it is usually not advisable to mock types that you don't own (see https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests).

And with JGit it is very simple to create test-repositories:

```java
public class JGitTest {

  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
  private Git git;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws GitAPIException {
    git = Git.init().setDirectory(tempFolder.getRoot()).call();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    git.getRepository().close();
  }

  @Test
  public void testFirst() {
    // with 'git' you have access to a fully functional repository
  }
}
```

See here for another example that initializes a repository and uses a `TemporaryFolder` to clean up: https://gist.github.com/rherrmann/5341e735ce197f306949fc58e9aed141

Answer (score 0):

I will add the answer [Rüdiger Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986905/r%C3%BCdiger-herrmann). After following steps it started working for me:

1. Annotate class `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`
2. `@Before` change on `@BeforeAll`
3. add `tempFolder.create();` to `setUp()` method